# Mongo Ruby 2.4 undefined method error when using minPoolSize optoin

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I recently upgraded to the Mongo Ruby driver version 2.4. When using `minPoolSize` as an option, I now get this error:

`` NoMethodError: undefined method `dispatch' for nil:NilClass
    from .../mongo-2.4.0/lib/mongo/operation/executable.rb:37:in `block in execute' ``

For example, this causes the error:

`with_options = "#{ENV['MONGO_URL']}?minPoolSize=10"
MONGO_DB = Mongo::Client.new(with_options)
MONGO_DB[:some_collection].find().first`

It looks like [this was talked about](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-741) a few years ago but other than that, I can't find any documentation on what the error means and why I can't use `minPoolSize`.

Comment: can you check your Gemfile.lock and tell me the version of mongo db ruby driver saved there?

Comment: @eiko `mongo (2.4.0)`, also fyi @Anthony's solution worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are not setting a `max_pool_size` greater than the min.  The default max is `5` and when the driver tries to dequeue a connection from the pool, it does a check:

```
    def create_connection
      if @connections < max_size
        @connections += 1
        @block.call
      end
    end
```

Here `@connections` is 10 but `max_size` was 5 and so this method returns `nil`.  Not a good client experience IMO so [I added a ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/RUBY-1201) to the ruby client's JIRA.  It's an API concern so I'm not sure how they'll want to handle it.

It will work if you set `max_pool_size` greater than `min_pool_size` like this:

```
MONGO_DB = Mongo::Client.new([ENV['MONGO_URL'], min_pool_size: 10, max_pool_size: 12)
```

of if you need to use the uri:

```
with_options = "#{ENV['MONGO_URL']}?minPoolSize=10&maxPoolSize=12"
MONGO_DB = Mongo::Client.new(with_options)
MONGO_DB[:example].find().first
```

Comment: have you tried this in url form like the asker was using? i had been wondering if it's actually a bug with url options vs hash options.

Comment: @eiko yes - the bug is present with either url or options hash.